# MVC 5 routing with 1 parameter

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I want the url to be

```
domain.com/doc/{project}
```

I have a controller called Projects or "ProjectsController.cs."
This controller has an action (ActionResult) I want to reach with my custom url route called "DocumentationIndex."

DocumentationIndex does have a parameter. It's a simple string parameter.

The following continues to give me a 404.

```
routes.MapRoute(
    name: "Documentation",
    url: "doc/{project}",
    defaults: new { controller = "Projects", action = "DocumentationIndex", project = "" }
);
```

Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Comment: What is the Exception being thrown, what is the message with the exception and what is the stack trace for the exception.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use attribute routing to define this within the controller:

```
public class ProjectsController 
{
     [Route("doc/{*project}")]
     public ActionResult DocumentationIndex(string project = "") 
     { // ... }
}
```

You'll need to ensure attribute routing is enabled in your Route Config:

```
routes.MapMvcAttributeRoutes();
```

The `*` in the `{*projects}` will ensure that the route parameter matches the rest of your URL, even if it contains special characters.

Comment: Thank you! However I have one problem that's really silly. What if there are dots in the string parameter? As in, "domain.com/doc/Project.v.2.1" The route seems to be working fine with one word parameters.

Comment: Unfortunately, the * did not make a difference. The 404 errors continues to persist. The simple one word no special chars strings still work though.

Comment: Fixed the dot(.) issue by adding the following to web.config.   `<system.webServer>
    <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true" />
  </system.webServer>`

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
routes.MapRoute(
    "Documentation",
    "doc/{project}",
    new { controller = "Projects", action = "DocumentationIndex" }
);
```

Your controller code:

```
public class ProjectsController ... {
    //
    public ActionResult DocumentationIndex(string project = "") {
        // ...
    }
}
```